# Building a Heap

Tags: c, heap

I'm trying to build a max heap out of a array of characters. Here is a piece of my code...

```
int arr_pos;
char inputArr[1000][51];

int buildMaxHeap(){
    int i;
    printf("test#1");
    for(i = arr_pos/2; i >= 0; i--){
        maxHeapify(i, arr_pos);
    }

    return 0;
}

void maxHeapify(int i, int heapsize){
    int largest, right, left;
    char *temp;
    left = 2*i + 1;
    right = 2*i + 2;
    if(left >= heapsize)
        return;
    else{
        if(left < (heapsize) && inputArr[left] > inputArr[i])
            largest = left;
        else
            largest = i;
        if(right < (heapsize) && inputArr[right] > inputArr[largest])
            largest = right;
        if(largest != i){
            temp = inputArr[i];
            strcpy(inputArr[i], inputArr[largest]);
            strcpy(inputArr[largest], temp);
            maxHeapify(largest, heapsize);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, say my heap contains (M, B, D, K, E, F) in that order. After I run my function the result comes out to (F, E, F, K, E, F). I know I have something wrong with my comparisons, but I can't find it.. Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: A [mcve], please.

Comment: Whoa, why do you `strcpy` around - you should use array of *pointers* to `char` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
        temp = inputArr[i];
        strcpy(inputArr[i], inputArr[largest]);
        strcpy(inputArr[largest], temp);
```

you're clobbering `inputArr[i]` with the first `strcpy`, so the second has no effect (you're copying the same string you just copied back).  You need to make `temp` an array (not a pointer) and copy (strcpy) `inputArr[i]` into it.

Comment: `strcpy` makes perfect sense for copying strings -- the elements of the heap are arrays that contain strings of up to 50 chars length.

Comment: It doesn't make perfect sense to be copying strings around in a heap when you can heapify an array of pointers

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I gave that a shot, but received a incompatible type error `incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[51]' from type 'char'`. Is there any way I could get around this? I also was using a array of pointers at first, but that lead to a whole different issue in my program. Because of that I switched to this.
Thank you again!

Comment: @DylanForsyth: you can't assign arrays -- you need to use `strcpy`

Comment: @ChrisDodd You're exactly right! Bonehead mistake on my part.. Thank you again for all the help!